# Issue in setting AbpUsers as foreign key in another table

Tags: foreign-keys, abp

We are using ABP.io in our project. We have requirement to map UserId as foreign key in my new table.

I mapped foreign key to new table as

```
public class NewEntity : FullAuditedEntity<int>, IHasIsActive
{
    ....    
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public IdentityUser AppUser { get; set; }
}
```

It successfully created foreign key relationship to AbpUsers table.

Now, I am trying to insert record in NewEntity table but it is throwing error

> The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be
>   defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call
>   'HasNoKey()'.

We have used CrudAppService in our code.

```
 public class NewEntityAppService :
        CrudAppService<NewEntity, NewEntityDto, int, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto,
                       CreateUpdatePropertyTypeDto, CreateUpdatePropertyTypeDto>,
        IPropertyTypeAppService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<NewEntity, int> _newType;
        public PropertyTypeAppService(IRepository<NewEntity, int> newType)
            : base(newType)
        {
            _newType= newType;
        }

    }
```

Error reference to the AppUser table because IdentityUser class has **IdentityUserLogin**. If I comment ForeignKey then it is working fine.

Need help to setup User ForeignKey properly.